# check the availability of username using php ajax code in a simpler way

Tags: php, ajax

I have a registration form in which all the fields are validated using JavaScript. I need to check the username availability , that is, whether that name already exists in my database(MySql) or not. If it exists simply an alert box should be popped saying "Username already exists" and the user should not be able to proceed to fill other fields. I need a simpler solution for this without jquery usage. Is there any solution for this using PHP and ajax?

Comment: just google it, u'll find bunch of ready made examples for sure..

Comment: @Asif Thanks for your suggestion. I did that but all examples shows the jquery code. I need to get it using php & ajax only.

Comment: Well if you are thinking `ajax` without JQuery than it is not going to be _simple_ at all..try searching ajax with JavaScript (will be more typical though)..

Comment: Don't validate fields through javascript. You'll end up getting weird data if people decides to use Firebug or disable javascript. You can have an ajax that gives and "OK" or an "Occupied" when username is typed. But in the end always validate through php and give errors accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Don't be lazy, do what you must do. =) If you begin to use other stuff than your ideas and experiences, you will just get bored and confused why your stuff is not working.
I think you may allow yourself to write oyur own little and simple jQuery request. It's only a few lines of code and it isn't Java so you will have to redesign the whole system just for a little modification... =)